# Refresh table after Ajax response(django)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I created a filter form and send it via ajax post request:

```
   $('#id_server').change(function(e) {
       $.post($("form").attr("action"), {
           action: 'filter',
           filter: $("#id_server").attr("name"),
           info: $("#id_server option:selected").attr("value"),
       }, function (response) {

       });
```

In the backend I filtering and recieving new `queryset` then I send new page to Ajax

The question is how load page from the ajax response to the screen or only 1 filtered tag?

Or may be there is a way to send and render new Query set from Django ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's .post() function has a callback function (the one with `response` as the argument). This function will be called when the AJAX is done loading.

It now depends how your Django backend is returning the result. If it's returning a piece of HTML you can directly insert it into your DOM using something like: `$(".result").html(response);`. Change the `.result` selector to the class or ID of your DOM node where it should place the result of your AJAX.

Comment: i only need to replace `<table>` tage and ajax respone is `<table># some new info</table>` If i aunderstand write i need `$("table").html(response);` ?

Comment: The .html function of jQuery changes the content of a DOM node, so if you'd try that code the result would be `<table><table>Some new info</table></table>`. Therefor you want to target the parent of your table. 
You should do that with either a unique class or ID. Because right now when selecting on just `table`, it doesn't matter which table it is, just any it finds in your website. Which is considered bad practice.